# Datetime format to Friendly Time. Moment JS Output is Wrong

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a very basic JS which converts datetime string to friendly format.

```
var raw = '2015-04-07 23:59:59';

var time = moment(raw, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS').format('MMMM do YYYY h:mm:ss a');
```

But this outputs `April 2nd 2015 11:59:59 pm` instead of `April 7th 2015 11:59:59 pm`. What am I doing wrong here?

JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sisir/ggvd853h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `do` should be capitalized, e.g: `var time = moment(raw, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS').format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a');` (See docs http://momentjs.com/)

That appears to work for me in your JSFiddle example.

Comment: Just figured it out myself! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

do: Day of week  (here 2nd day)

Do: Day of month (7th)

So

`format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a')` will work